# to prove the Cohen theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Now given a fact that I had proven:

If $I$ is an ideal in a commutative ring $R$ such that $I$ is not finitely generated but every ideal properly containing $I$ is finitely generated, then $I$ is a prime ideal.

My question is how to use this fact to prove the Cohen theorem: If every prime ideal of $R$ is finitely generated, then $R$ is noetherian.

My attempt is: suppose not, then there is an ideal not finitely generated, but didn't know how to derive any contradictions. (I don't think the ideal properly containing it are all finitely generated?)

Thanks for any helps in advance!

Added:

I asked this question for I just want to know if I can reach the conclusion without the axiom of choice, and after thinking these hours and with the comment and answer from you deer, I think that is unavoidable. Thank you all guys!

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt, but I'd consider the set of all ideals $J \subset R$ such that $J$ is not finitely generated and apply Zorn's Lemma. That should give you and ideal $J^{*}$ satisfying the hypothesis of the fact you proved, so $J^{*}$ is prime. So you just found a prime ideal not finitely generated, contradicting the hypothesis. This contradiction comes from assuming the set of ideals on $R$ not finitely generated is non-empty, so it must be empty. Therefore every ideal of $R$ is finitely generated, so $R$ is noetherian.

Comment: All right,... so I doubt this way didn't shorten the proof than showing it directly haha thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If there is an ideal not finitely generated then the family $$\{I\subset R; I \text{ is an ideal not finitely generated 
}\}$$ is not empty. Now try using Zorn Lemma over this family.

Comment: Right! I just believed I can avoid Zorn's lemma by this approach but now I think it must fail...Thanks!